# Opsworks recipe management best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I was wondering what other peoples opinions are of using default Chef Recipes provided by Amazon. For example I'm depending heavily on: https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_nodejs and was wondering if it's good practice to keep relying on those in the future.

I could easily fork the cookbooks/recipes that I'm using so that they don't change to mitigate future changes to these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost entirely opinion based and thus not really something SO is good to answer. On the objective side you can say that they are open source and thus even if AWS stops development or does things you don't like, at worst you can still fork them. I don't think Opsworks has been around long enough for anyone to talk about "best practices" with a straight face. Chef is ~5 years old and we're only just barely figuring out how to write cookbooks properly.

Comment: Yah, that's what I was thinking as well but it's always good to get feedback from others who have much more experience with Chef. I'm glad I asked!